# mysql choosing values with certain condition

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have two tables in Mysql database:
 let them be `students_info` and `groups_info`. 
`Students_info` contains following columns: `firstname, lastname,group_id(foreign key)`.
 `Groups_info` contains: `group_name, group_id(primary key)`. 
What query should I write if I want to display all students that study in a group with a certain group_name.
 Like I choose a `group_name` from a combobox or smith and get a table with enrolled students. maybe smth to do with aliases?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it is a simple JOIN between the two tables

```
SELECT si.firstname, si.lastname, gi.group_name
FROM students_info si inner join groups_info gi on si.group_id = gi.group_id
WHERE gi.group_name = @yourselectedgroupname
```

in your code you write something like this

```
string cmdText = @"SELECT si.firstname, si.lastname, gi.group_name
FROM students_info si inner join groups_info gi on si.group_id = gi.group_id
WHERE gi.group_name = @grp"

string grpName = comboGroups.Text;
using(MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cn))
{
   cn.Open();
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grp", grpName);
   using(MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
   {
      DataTable tb = new DataTable();
      da.Fill(tb);
      gridView.DataSource = tb;
   }
}
```